# Errors converting from UTF-8 to latin1 using Iconv

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, iconv

Total Ruby noob, just trying to hack a script to make it work.

```
irb(main):011:0> Iconv.iconv("LATIN1//IGNORE", "UTF-8", "Résumé")
Iconv::InvalidCharacter: "\351"
    from (irb):11:in `iconv'
    from (irb):11
    from :0
irb(main):012:0> Iconv.iconv("LATIN1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", "UTF-8", "Résumé")
Iconv::IllegalSequence: "\351sum\351"
    from (irb):12:in `iconv'
    from (irb):12
    from :0
irb(main):002:0> "Résumé".encoding
NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for "R\351sum\351":String
    from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's interpreting your input string as LATIN1 already, you can't convert it along that path. You may need to set your encoding to be UTF-8 to start. `\351` is a LATIN1 `é` character.

You want the following result:

```
"Résumé".encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

You could check your `LANG` environment variable, or whatever your platform uses to determine the default character encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is what I get: irb(main):002:0> "Résumé".encoding
NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for "R\351sum\351":String
        from (irb):2

Comment: Looks like you're using Ruby 1.8.x then. It's mostly ignorant about character encodings, so it'll be subject to whatever terminal or command prompt you're using. You can check what's in the string by using: `'Résumé'.unpack("C*")` to examine the raw bytes and you should see `[82, 195, 169, 115, 117, 109, 195, 169]` if you're in UTF-8 mode, or `[82, 233, 115, 117, 109, 233]` if in LATIN1.